# How to prevent Firebase Firestore adding new doc on every character Press?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a page that allows users to input coupon codes.

The user simply inputs a code and presses submit.

I am using Firebase Firestore to manage the data. The application works as designed, except it adds the code to Firestore on every keypress, instead of just when the full coupon code has been entered.

For example, for the code "ABC123", the backend adds 6 different codes:

"A"
"AB"
"ABC"
"ABC1"
"ABC12"
"ABC123"

Please let me know if you are able to assist! Thank you so much

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { collection, getCountFromServer, getFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../firebase';
import ProgressBar from "@ramonak/react-progress-bar";
import "./gauge.css"

require("firebase/compat/firestore")
  
// import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    


  const CodeEnter = () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const [code, setCode] = useState("");
    const [codesTotal, setCodesTotal] = useState(0);


    // console.log("firebase.auth().currentUser.uid", firebase.firestore().collection('users') )

    useEffect(()=> {
      const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          if (user) {
            const asyncFunction = async () => {
              const db = getFirestore(app);
              const userID = firebase.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
              const coll = collection(db, "users", userID, "codes");
              const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(coll);
              const codesTotal = snapshot?.data()?.count
              // console.log('codesTotal = snapshot.data().count',snapshot.data().count)
              setCodesTotal(codesTotal);
              }
              asyncFunction(); 
          } else {
              console.log("Not logged in")
          } 
      })
      return () => {
          listen();
      }
  }, [])

    
      const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth()?.currentUser?.uid).collection("codes")
    //console.log("Length--->",firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth()?.currentUser?.uid).collection("codes").count())
      
    
    
    docRef.add({
        code,
        creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })

    let rewardsMessage = ""
    if (codesTotal > 0 && codesTotal < 25 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${25 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      
    }
    else if (codesTotal >=25 && codesTotal < 50 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${50 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 25 codes reached for user`)
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >50 && codesTotal < 100 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${100 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 50 codes reached for user`)

    } 
    else if (codesTotal >100 && codesTotal < 250 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${250 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 100 codes reached for user`)
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >250 && codesTotal < 500 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${500 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 250 codes reached for user`)
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >500 && codesTotal < 1000 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${1000 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 500 codes reached for user`)

    } 
    else if (codesTotal >1000 && codesTotal < 2000 ) {
      rewardsMessage = `Only ${2000 - codesTotal} more codes until your next reward!`
      console.log(`Threshold of 1000 codes reached for user`)

    } 

    let codePct = 0 

    if (codesTotal > 0 && codesTotal < 25 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 25
    }
    else if (codesTotal >=25 && codesTotal < 50 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 50
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >=50 && codesTotal < 100 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 100
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >=100 && codesTotal < 250 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 250
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >=250 && codesTotal < 500 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 500
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >=500 && codesTotal < 1000 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 1000
    } 
    else if (codesTotal >=1000 && codesTotal < 2000 ) {
      codePct = codesTotal / 500
    } 



  return (
    <div className='sign-in-container'>
        <form onSubmit={CodeEnter}>
            <h1>Enter your code</h1>
            <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder='Enter your Code' 
            value={code}
            onChange={(e)=> {setCode(e.target.value)}}
            ></input>
            <button type="submit">Redeem Code</button>
        </form>
        <div>
          <p>{`Total Codes Redeemed: ${codesTotal}`}</p>
          <p>{rewardsMessage}</p>
          
        </div>
        <div style={{
          width: '50%',
          justifyContent:'center',
          margin: 'auto'
          
          }}>
        <ProgressBar 
        completed={Math.round(codePct * 100)}
        className="wrapper"
        barContainerClassName="container"
        labelClassName="label"
        bgColor='#008000'
        margin='2000'
        padding='2000'
        labelAlignment='right'
        borderRadius='2px'
         />
         </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default CodeEnter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore adds a new document whenever you call `docRef.add(...)`. In your current code that happens for every call to `CodeEnter`, which apparently happens on every keypress.

If you want to only add the new document when the full coupon code has been entered, you should only call `docRef.add(...)` when the full coupon code has been entered. It's not immediately clear to me from the code/information you shared when that is.

Comment: Thank you Frank. The docRef.add(...) is triggered on the onSubmit in the form. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: From the behavior you describe the `docRef.add(...)` gets triggerd on more than just form submission. I'd put a breakpoint on that line, running in the debugger and then seeing when/from where it gets triggered.

Comment: Did you get any more additional insight from debugging the problem?

Comment: Hi Frank, I did not unfortunately. I am only calling the docRef.add(...) when the onSubmit on the form triggers the CodeEnter fn. Please let me know if you are able to assist me with this, as I am stuck and looking to learn. Thank you so much